# Como se chama a parte da lata que serve para a abrir?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

“Todas”  as latas de refrigerante têm uma certa parte, no topo, que server para empurrar a aba, e abrir a lata. Como se chama essa parte?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Em Portugal o nome dado a essa parte da lata é anilha de lata.

Comment: Oh, ok; então não há uma palavra única para este objeto?

Comment: Ha, e anilha de lata. A mencao a carica foi relativamente a resposta do JorgeB. Ja editei a resposta.

Comment: Eu li a pergunta mas ficou-me na cabeça a carica de lata, foi simplesmente engano mental :P

Comment: Alguma referência a um dicionário que possua essa definição? Também concordo com _anilha_, mas de tudo o que encontrei, apenas mencionam a peça metálica usada para proteger peças de madeira.

Comment: @E_net4 referencia a dicionário para "anilha em lata" não. Ate porque anilha e um termo geral que identifica vários objectos. A parte "em lata" e que a associa as latas de refrigerantes/conservas.

Comment: Eu acho que o nome "anilha" foi dado devido à [sua forma original](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Beverage_pull_tab.jpg/260px-Beverage_pull_tab.jpg), mesmo que agora ele tem [uma forma diferente](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/Can_top_closeup.png/320px-Can_top_closeup.png).

Comment: Já vi isso chamado de "[patilha](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/patilha)" ([exemplo](http://dicasdamadalena.blogspot.pt/2012/11/dica-ganhar-espaco.html)), mas pode ser que tenha sido por confusão com "anilha"

Answer (score 13):

No Brasil essa parte da lata é comumente chamada de "anel" ou ainda "lacre" da lata ou latinha.
Veja alguns exemplos de buscas no google que retornam resultados usando esse termo (creio eu que isso comprove seu uso cotidiano)

- [O anel da lata se recicla separado](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=O%20anel%20da%20lata%20se%20recicla%20separado&oq=O%20anel%20da%20lata%20se%20recicla%20separado&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.1208j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)?
- [Como é feito o lacre da lata?](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Como%20%C3%A9%20feito%20o%20lacre%20da%20lata%3F)
- [Roupa criada com anel de latinha](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=roupa%20feita%20de%20anel%20de%20latinha)

Answer (score -1):

O nome correto dado a peça que possui um orifício para abertura da lata de cerveja ou refrigerante é lacre.

Comment: Boas-vindas, Márcio. Obrigado pela contribuição, mas note que, primeiro, geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas (por exemplo com referências) e, segundo, que uma [resposta mais antiga](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/295/2764) já citava "lacre" como uma possibilidade: caso em que o mais recomendável é votar positivamente (seta para cima à esquerda da postagem) a resposta já existente ao invés de postar nova resposta com mesmo conteúdo.